# México D.F. appering as M??xico D.F. on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, ascii

I am sending a text **México D.F.**  from javascript to  C# but i am getting **M??xico D.F.**.
My C# code is below.

```
public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
{
     System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
     string PostbackData = enc.GetString(context.Request.BinaryRead(context.Request.TotalBytes));
}
```

PostbackData contains  **México D.F.**  text as **M??xico D.F.**.
How can i resolve it. Please help me.

Comment: `é` is not ASCII...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ASCII`, as there is no such symbol `é` there, so use [Encoding.UTF8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) instead:

```
using System.Text;

public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
{
     //System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
     string postbackData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(context.Request.BinaryRead(context.Request.TotalBytes));
}
```

**Edit, as John Skeet mentioned**: You can use Encoding from your request rather than try to guess it - sometimes even UTF-8 is not enough, so better approach is:

```
using System.Text;

public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
{
     //System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
     string postbackData = context.Request.ContentEncoding.GetString(context.Request.BinaryRead(context.Request.TotalBytes));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using `ASCIIEncoding` (and creating a new instance of it for no obvious reason - prefer the factory properties in `Encoding`). ASCII doesn't contain any accented characters.

EDIT: You should use the [`HttpRequest.ContentEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.contentencoding.aspx) property to determine the encoding from the headers of the request, rather than hard-coding it:

```
 HttpRequest request = context.Request;
 byte[] binaryData = request.BinaryRead(context.Request.TotalBytes);
 string postbackData = request.ContentEncoding.GetString(binaryData);
```

Note that it's almost *never* a good idea to use a fully-qualified name within the body of your code. Add `using` directives instead. Also note that local variables in C# are usually camelCased rather than PascalCased.